# How to partition a USB drive into 2 sections for Centos ISO files

Tags: linux, hard-drive, usb, partitioning, centos

I actually once did this but forgot how it's done and also did not take notes.

i think i need to create 2 partitions.

one needs to be 500 mb and the rest needs to me whatever is left in the USB drive.

- first one needs to be `FAT32`
- second one needs to be..`ext3`

how can i do this ?

note: my usb is currently : /dev/sdb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly the same way you would on a hard disk.

This could be as easy as using "FDISK /dev/sdb" from the command line.   You do, of-course, need to set up the appropriate partition types and format them.  Try the following from a command line:

```
fdisk /dev/sdb
d
1         [ to remove pre-existing partition]
n
p
1
[enter]
+500M
t
c        [ to create primary 500 meg partition for fat]
n
p
2
[enter]
[enter]
t
2
83       [ to create second partition for ext3 ]
w

Type "sync" to force in-memory changes to disk.  (Or you could wait an indeterminate period of time !)

Then remove the disk and reinsert it so its reread.

mkfs.vfat /dev/sdb1     [ to Create a FAT partition on the ppe rimary partition ]
mkfs.ext3 dev/sdb2      [ to Create an EXT3 partition on the secondary partition ]
```